# Rule of Three for a class Queue using a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I need to create a copy constructor and an assignment operator for my class Queue, but I am a bit confused on how to go about it (I should also probably build a destructor to follow the rule of three).

I built my queue using another class "list" which is a linked list. Should I be building them using similar functions in my class "list" (like should I have a destructor, assignment operator and a copy constructor in my class "list" and call them in my class queue)? Or, can I build them directly using my class "queue"?

Below is my class "queue"

```
class Queue {
 private:
    List list;
 public:
  Queue (){
      // I may need a default constructor
  }
  Queue(const Queue &other){
      /* copy constructor. This and the assignment operator are only things I am currently
         concerned with, but I probably should do the rest to follow the rule of three */
  }
  ~Queue(){
      // destructor
  }
  Queue operator= ( const Queue &other){
      // Assignment Operator.
  }
  // I have these working
  void push(Item);
  void pop();
  Item & peek();
  bool empty();
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you consult this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three/4172724#4172724](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three/4172724#4172724)

Comment: Not yet, but I will right now:)

Comment: The beauty of the rule of 3/5/0 is that if `List` respects that rule, then you don't need to implement any of those special members for `Queue` ( you apply rue 0 to `Queue`).

Comment: Reading about "ownership" is good. Leaving halfbaked classes around isn't nice.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I got it worked out by applying the rule of three to my class "list"